# JavaScript: How to Display only One Array Item interpolated into a string?

Tags: javascript

Most of the code has been changed from the main source code I've changed from this site: NewRetroWave Name Generator:
https://codepen.io/njmcode/details/JdRaWX

The site above with their code snippets utilize the jQuery library. As for my project I am only using JavaScript, HTML and CSS.

```
const arrayOne = [one, two, three, four, five,];
```

The code above is the array in which is outputting all items into the code below
in which **I want to display only one item** as I generate the code through an HTML button function.

```
const sentenceOne = [`Your generated item is: ${arrayOne}`, `Random Item Generated: ${arrayOne}`, `Generated: ${arrayOne}`];
```

```js
const arrayOne = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

const sentenceOne = [`Your generated item is: ${arrayOne}`, `Random Item Generated: ${arrayOne}`, `Generated: ${arrayOne}`];

function randMathFunc(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

const initialize = (function(){

    function randArray(generateArray) {
        return generateArray[randMathFunc(0, generateArray.length - 1)];
    }
    
    function generateItem() {
        var itm1Gen = randMathFunc(1, 1),
        itm1Name = [];

        for (n = 0; n < itm1Gen; n++) {
            var complete = false;
            while (!complete) {
                let newItm1Gen = randArray(items);
                if (itm1Name.indexOf(newItm1Gen) == -1) {

                    itm1Name.push(newItm1Gen);

                    complete = true;

                }

            }

        }

        var itemKey = itm1Name.join( " " );
        return itemKey;

    }

    function displayItem(item){
        document.getElementById( 'itemkeyname' ).innerHTML = item;
    }

    function contentRetriever() {
        let item = generateItem();

        displayItem(item);

    }

    function runProgram() {
        items = sentenceOne;

        contentRetriever();

        document.getElementById( 'generatebutton' ).onclick = function () {

            let item = generateItem();
            displayItem( item );

        }

    }

    return {
        init: runProgram
    }

})();

initialize.init();
```

```css
html {

    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 255px;
    padding-bottom: 255px;
    padding-right: 55px;
    padding-left: 55px;

}

h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

head, h1, h3 {

    position: static;
    text-align: center;

    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
    
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    
}


#itemkeyname {
    
    position: static;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

#contentGenerate, #generatebutton {

    position: static;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: monospace;

}

#generatebutton {

    border-top: 0.5px;
    border-bottom: 0.5px;
    border-style: none;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="snippet.css" />

</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapped">

            <div id="insideItems">
                <div id="itemkeyname"></div>
            </div>
    
    </div>

    <div id="itemArrayGenerate">
            <button type="button" 
            id="generatebutton" 
            value="generate">Generate</button>
    </div>

    <script src="snippet.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Since, my question appears to be vague, please give me a heads up on what you want me to upload.

Here is the output:
[Writing Prompt Generator output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxXKH.png)

This is the output of my writing prompt generator, as you can see it outputs the whole array rather than one item from said array.

Comment: What are `[one, two, three, four, five,];`? Hard to replicate the problem you're having, because these variables aren't defined - can you fix your snippet so that it runs?

Comment: Whoops. Just realised they were supposed to be strings! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your currently only using `arrayOne`, the array of random words, in your `sentenceOne` array:

```
const sentenceOne = [`Your generated item is: ${arrayOne}`, `Random Item Generated: ${arrayOne}`, `Generated: ${arrayOne}`];
```

But you've *hard-coded* `arrayOne` into each `sentence`. `sentenceOne` is now, exactly:

```
[
  "Your generated item is: one,two,three,four,five",
  "Random Item Generated: one,two,three,four,five",
  "Generated: one,two,three,four,five"
]
```

When generating a random string, you need to *both* pick a random prefix string (`Generated ...`) *and* a random item from `arrayOne`. I'd suggest defining `sentenceOne` sentences to include only the prefix strings, and then when generating a new item, call `randArray` on *both* the `arrayOne` and the `sentenceOne`:

```
let newItm1Gen = randArray(items) + randArray(arrayOne);
```

```js
const arrayOne = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

const sentenceOne = [`Your generated item is: `, `Random Item Generated: `, `Generated: `];

function randMathFunc(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

const initialize = (function() {

  function randArray(generateArray) {
    return generateArray[randMathFunc(0, generateArray.length - 1)];
  }

  function generateItem() {
    var itm1Gen = randMathFunc(1, 1),
      itm1Name = [];
    for (n = 0; n < itm1Gen; n++) {
      var complete = false;
      while (!complete) {
        let newItm1Gen = randArray(items) + randArray(arrayOne);
        if (itm1Name.indexOf(newItm1Gen) == -1) {
          itm1Name.push(newItm1Gen);
          complete = true;

        }

      }

    }
    var itemKey = itm1Name.join(" ");
    return itemKey;

  }

  function displayItem(item) {
    document.getElementById('itemkeyname').innerHTML = item;
  }

  function contentRetriever() {
    let item = generateItem();

    displayItem(item);

  }

  function runProgram() {
    items = sentenceOne;

    contentRetriever();

    document.getElementById('generatebutton').onclick = function() {

      let item = generateItem();
      displayItem(item);

    }

  }

  return {
    init: runProgram
  }

})();

initialize.init();
```

```css
html {
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 255px;
  padding-bottom: 255px;
  padding-right: 55px;
  padding-left: 55px;
}

h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

head,
h1,
h3 {
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#itemkeyname {
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#contentGenerate,
#generatebutton {
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}

#generatebutton {
  border-top: 0.5px;
  border-bottom: 0.5px;
  border-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="snippet.css" />

</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapped">

    <div id="insideItems">
      <div id="itemkeyname"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="itemArrayGenerate">
    <button type="button" id="generatebutton" value="generate">Generate</button>
  </div>

  <script src="snippet.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is the one! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understood what you need but, if you need to get a random item from array that's the way.

```
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];

function randomItemFromArray(arr){
   return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
}
```

Comment: This code is already implemented into the question presented. It's just me trying to figure out how to specifically display only one randomly generated item from an array at a time.